# PythonNET: C# function does not modify class instanced passed to it

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, python.net, pythonnet

I have a C# class like

```
public MY_CLASS(int number)
        {
            SomeField = number;
            SetElseWhere = 0;
        }
    }
```

that I want to pass to a C# function like

```
public static bool MyTask(string pathXML, out MY_CLASS test)
```

I expect `MyTask` to modify the field `SetElseWhere` in an instance of `MY_CLASS`

In PythonNet I call the function like

```
import System

my_dll = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile('example.dll')
MY_CLASS_t = my_dll.GetType('NAMESPACE.MY_CLASS')

my_instance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(MY_CLASS_t)

x = MyTask('test.xml', my_instance)
```

Now it is getting strange, at least to me:

The returned value x is a tuple with two entries, a boolan and an object
of type `NAMESPACE.MY_CLASS`. But it is not the instance that I sent in as second parameter stated with property `out`.

When I check the results I can see that the object in the returned
tuple has been modified correctly, but the instance I send in
has not been modified.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You have to use the out modifier when you pass in the object: x = MyTask("test.xml", out my_instance);

Comment: You mean in the Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood your problem and this issue is not documented. There is no concept of out/ref arguments in Python, hence the modifications to arguments are returned in the tuple.

Here is an open issue about this:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/228